# Cannot install Spring STS and Microservices Plugins on Eclipse Neon.3

Tags: spring, eclipse, microservices

I am not able to install Spring STS and Microservices plug-ins to my Eclipse Neon.3. I get the following error -
[image]

Comment: Please copy the error message (which is not readable in the screenshot) into your question. Are there any reasons to use such an old Eclipse version?

Comment: This eclipse version was installed last year, so far working perfectly fine with other plug-ins. I will paste the error message soon. Thanks.

Comment: When I try to install the "Microservices plug-in", I get the following errors in the error log - 

No repository found at http://oneclicklabs.io/repo/eclipse/plugin/microservices/v1/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/.

Comment: Please add the error message into your question formatted as code snippet. Eclipse Neon is outdated and no longer maintained. Three new main releases have been released in the meantime. Indeed, both repositories no longer exist. Please upgrade and try again.

Comment: will Eclipse Oxygen be ok?

Comment: Whenever a new main release is published, this means the end of maintenance for the previous release. The current release is 2018-09.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am following this page - https://moduliertersingvogel.de/2017/07/30/update-eclipse-from-neon-to-oxygen/

Comment: I gave the website name - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-09/ instead of Oxygen

Comment: Let's see if I am able to install the Microservices / STS plug-ins now...

Comment: No, I am still getting the same error - No repository found at http://oneclicklabs.io/repo/eclipse/plugin/microservices/v1/.

Comment: Do you talk about [this Eclipse Marketplace entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/microservices-plugin-eclipse)? It looks the repository disappeared two months ago (see metrics: no installations since September). Please contact the owner of oneclicklabs.io. As a workaround, you can [download the update site as ZIP from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/microservices-plugin/files/MicroservicesPlugin.zip/download) and install it via _Help > Install New Software..._, click _Add..._ and then _Archive..._.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your suggestion. Microservices plug-in has been installed successfully. Now, I need the same plug-ins for Spring, Spring boot, etc. to work on microservices. Could you please send me the links from where I can get the plugins for Spring / STS ?

Comment: The same place you were trying to install this: the Marketplace.